# ServiceStack AuthFeature assign and unassign roles

Tags: servicestack

Do the `AuthFeature` `AssignRoles` and `UnassignRoles` endpoints require any permissions or roles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need the *Admin* role.

From the ServiceStack [source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AssignRolesService.cs):

```cs
[RequiredRole(RoleNames.Admin)]
[DefaultRequest(typeof(AssignRoles))]
public class AssignRolesService : Service
{
   ...
}
```

Same role requirement for `UnassignRolesService`.

Comment: To add to this, you can also change the RoleNames.Admin value to a string of your choice. It's just a public static string.